# ionic 4 + laravel Api authentification

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm building an Ionic app and trying to use Laravel 6as my API.When i try to log in show me that my credentials are wrong"'Wrong credentials ! try again'"  . Despite in postman it work .I have try many ways but it didnt work So any help gyus
this my auth provider auts.ts :

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
 import {xxx} from "../../app/apiurls/serverurls.js";
 import { Http , Headers } from '@angular/http';

 @Injectable()
 export class AuthProvider {
 public token:any;
 constructor(public storage:Storage ,public http: Http) {
 console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
 }
 login(credentials){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
  headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
  headers.append('Accept','application/json');
  headers.append('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');

    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), 
   {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {
        let data = res.json();
        this.token = data.token;
        this.storage.set('token', data.token);
        resolve(data);
        }, (err) => {
        reject(err);

      });  });

 }
 checkAuthentication(){

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {

  this.token = value;

  resolve(this.token)


})
});
}
logout(){
this.storage.set('token', '');

 }

 }
```

and this is my login.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';
 @IonicPage()
 @Component({
 selector: 'page-login',
 templateUrl: 'login.html',
 })
 export class LoginPage {
 email:string = '';
 password:string = '';
errorMsg:string;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
public navParams: NavParams,
public authService: AuthProvider ,
 public alertCtrl: AlertController ,
)  {
 }
 ionViewDidLoad() {
 console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
 }
 errorFunc(message){
 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'oops!',
  subTitle: message,
  buttons: ['OK']
   });
   alert.present();
   }
   myLogIn(){

   if (this.email.trim() !==''    ) {
   console.log(this.email.trim() + "   " + this.password.trim() )
   if (this.password.trim()  === '') {
    this.errorFunc('Please put your password')
   }
    else{
    let credentials = {
      email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    };
     this.authService.login(credentials).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);

    }, (err) => {

        console.log(err);
        this. errorFunc('Wrong credentials ! try again')
        console.log("credentials: "+JSON.stringify(credentials))

    });

  }

 }
 else{

 this. errorFunc('Please put a vaild password !  for ex:(123456)')

  }



 }
myLogOut(){
 this.authService.logout();
}



}
```

i'm so confused i thing the code is correct but really what's wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to test in the browser with `ionic cordova run browser` ? For example, in Chrome you could use the Developers Tools Network tab to check to see what message the API is returning.

Comment: ye i know 
it return me 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOM' of undefined
    at CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest (xhr_backend.js:167)
    at XHRBackend.createConnection (xhr_backend.js:207)
    at httpRequest (http.js:20)
    at Http.request (http.js:120)
    at Http.post (http.js:137)
    at auth.ts:30
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at AuthProvider.webpackJsonp.162.AuthProvider.login (auth.ts:21)
    at LoginPage.webpackJsonp.111.LoginPage.myLogIn (login.ts:71)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginPage.html:32)

Comment: i dont think the problem is not in  the api but with  @angular/http @nathan

Comment: There could be a multitude of things causing that error. The most likely cause is libraries not being their correct respective versions, so maybe double check what versions you are using (especially for the HTTP library). Also, you are setting your CORS headers within your client. CORS headers should be handled by the server (Laraval), not the client. Adding them to your client is pretty useless, by setting them in your server, you're telling clients that connect to the server what Domains (origins), methods, and content types are allowed to be sent to the API.